# Can one AJAX request "steal" the results of another?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm experiencing an AJAX/JS bug that I'm not able to reproduce, but I have a theory about. Basically, my web page makes an AJAX call every 10 seconds to update various elements with new data. There is also a button the user can press which invokes a different AJAX call, which also updates some of the same elements.

If the button is never pressed, no bug will occur. However, in some rare cases, the page gets all screwed up with incorrect data shortly after pressing the button. The data "seems" like it might be coming from a different source. Is it possible that one of the AJAX calls is receiving and outputting the results of the other? Both functions include:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
```

Is there maybe a global overwrite going on here?
Thanks

Comment: no. each ajax request would be its own separate http connection.

Comment: hmmm. If there is an `xmlhttp` variable in the outer scope when that function is declared it could get interesting. Best to use the `var` keyword whenever the variable should be only in the current scope: `var xmlhttp = ...`

Comment: It's important to note though, that the browser is probably not giving the results of one ajax call to the callback of another. That does not, however, exempt you from inadvertently writing code which assumes it knows which response it is dealing with when it actually doesn't.